# c++ crash when calling std::vector::clear

Tags: c++, crash, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<Pointer>` where pointer is very similar to Boost's intrusive ptr. There are a couple of differences but the system worked well so for months and I have any doubts that it has any flaws. The vector contains a list of ~30 interfaces and each element has an implementation to rather complex objects. The crash happens as follows:

```
v.clear() // -> CRASH
```

Strangely the crash doesn't happen if clear the vector in any other way; for example the following code will NOT crash.

```
while(v.size()) v.pop_back();
or
while(v.size()) v.erase(v.begin());
```

It also doesn't crash if I compile with the flags "/RTCsu" and "/RTCc".
If I debug the release of all the items happens correctly, it will even exit the clear function successfully, however if eminently after the clear I do "step into" it will go again in the clear function and will crash upon calling the function "iterator end()"

How is this happening ? What part of the memory should I check for corruption, since the debugger and Application verifier failed to give me any relevant information?
Has anyone stumbled upon this issue before?

Comment: Hard to tell without more code. My guess it that one of the destructors of the contained objects crashes.

Comment: Yes, I agree with mirk. 80%~

Comment: I would check the implementation of your smart pointer. I suppose it doesn't follow the rule of three, or something like that

Comment: I agree with healer - to the extent I'm tempted to add an answer. :-) Suggest that "Pointer"'s reference counting and temporary objects in the last two examples are leaving a pointer wrapped in a "Pointer" undeleted, but not in the first example where in the context of your program something is likely being deleted twice.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa236698%28v=vs.60%29.aspx . Have a look here and see if any of your issues are related to what is pointed out here.

Comment: why don't you use well tested and well supported smart pointers? (like those provided by boost or by the c++11 standard). Very likely that your own pointer is faulty (or the objects pointed to). `std::vector::clear()` is almost certainly okay.

Comment: @Walter, every c++ programmer has to write his own smart pointer at some point in his career %)

Comment: @aleguna I never did. but then I'm not a professional programmer ;)

Comment: Does any of your objects have a (destructor with a) dependency back to the vector that contains it? The vector's state could be unreliable during the `clear()` call.

Comment: @Walter special purpose intrusive smart pointers are occasionally worth writing yourself; its the general purpose wrappers like `shared` and `unique` which are probably not worth re-inventing.

Comment: -1 for the assumption that your code has no flaws.

Comment: The crash is not happening in the destructors , i have checked all of them , and as i specified in the description, the vector safely clears all the values. What i would like to know is how the clear function can be called again after it exited.

Comment: whell , recompiling the whole project fixed it. i suspected a compiler bug

Comment: Open the core file and check the stack trace.  That will let you know where the crash occurred and whether or not your code is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Is that smart pointer has copy constructor and assignment operator? STL containers store copies of contained items, if there is something wrong with your smart pointer, that might have caused the problem that you described.

Comment: Correction, if there is something wrong with the copy ctor or assignment operator, that might cause the problem.